# Transformation of a vector to a data frame with two columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, transform

I have the following dataset, it consists of ID's (integer, although all is stored as a factor) and units of time, which belong to the ID above (see an excerpt of data below, total data has 300'000+ values).

```
10000007
01:33:28
00:00:05
10000010
00:00:39
00:02:21
00:05:59
00:40:40
00:09:53
10000014
00:09:37
00:00:00
00:00:15
00:00:02
00:40:51
10000022
00:41:44
01:32:32
10000023
01:07:14
01:25:27
1000003
00:00:58
00:03:42
00:05:58
00:00:29
00:00:01
00:04:02
00:00:10
00:01:08
00:07:52
00:10:18
00:12:52
00:09:39
00:07:48
00:04:29
```

What I want is a data frame, which has in one column the ID and the other column the time. Something like this:

```
10000007  01:33:28
10000007  00:00:05
10000010  00:00:39
10000010  00:02:21
10000010  00:05:59
10000010  00:40:40
10000010  00:09:53
10000014  00:09:37
10000014  00:00:00
10000014  00:00:15
10000014  00:00:02
10000014  00:40:51
...
```

I struggle with the fact that the number of time stamps differs between the different ID's and the fact that I can't change the format to numeric efficiently, which might make the operation handier.

Eventually, the idea is to have the times summed up to have only one time per ID. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: May we ask what your source data actually looks like?  If possible, you should probably fix the data at the source, and get it into a more usable form.

Comment: There was a question recently (https://stackoverflow.com/q/59650616/5325862) with a similar procedure but different way of marking off IDs vs values. But you could look there for help with the logic of this

Comment: Unclear to me how the two types of data relate to each other. For example, are 01:33:28 (2nd row) and 00:00:05 (3rd row) observations on ID 10000007? If so, then the ID should be repeated in the two-column dataframe, correct?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're absolutely right. The source data is an xml file and I've struggled greatly to extract the data like this with parsing in python in the first place, as I'm a novice with python or the xml structure.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann yes you are very right! That's exactly what I had been looking for.

Comment: Sorry, unclear what you mean by "that's exactly what I was looking for". Did you mean my comment above or the answer I posted yesterday but deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `stack`

```
i1 <- !grepl(":", df$V1)
out <- stack(setNames(split(df$V1[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1]), df$V1[i1]))[2:1]
head(out)
#    ind   values
#1 10000007 01:33:28
#2 10000007 00:00:05
#3 10000010 00:00:39
#4 10000010 00:02:21
#5 10000010 00:05:59
#6 10000010 00:40:40


dim(out)
#[1] 30  2
```

---

Or it can be done with `data.frame` call

```
data.frame(V1 = df$V1[i1][cumsum(i1)], V2 = df$V1)[!i1,]
```

Or with `transform`

```
transform(df, V2 = V1[i1][cumsum(i1)])[!i1,]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("10000007", "01:33:28", "00:00:05", "10000010", 
"00:00:39", "00:02:21", "00:05:59", "00:40:40", "00:09:53", "10000014", 
"00:09:37", "00:00:00", "00:00:15", "00:00:02", "00:40:51", "10000022", 
"00:41:44", "01:32:32", "10000023", "01:07:14", "01:25:27", "1000003", 
"00:00:58", "00:03:42", "00:05:58", "00:00:29", "00:00:01", "00:04:02", 
"00:00:10", "00:01:08", "00:07:52", "00:10:18", "00:12:52", "00:09:39", 
"00:07:48", "00:04:29")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. With your first approach, I received an error message ``` Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [321879] must be the same length as the vector [12893] ```. The data.frame function worked flawlessly.

Comment: @YvesR  with the data in my post, sorry  I couldn't reproduce the error.  May be, there is a different issue with `stack`

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = cumsum(grepl("^100", V1))) %>%
 mutate(V2 = first(V1)) %>%
 slice(-1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp) 

   V1       V2      
   <chr>    <chr>   
 1 01:33:28 10000007
 2 00:00:05 10000007
 3 00:00:39 10000010
 4 00:02:21 10000010
 5 00:05:59 10000010
 6 00:40:40 10000010
 7 00:09:53 10000010
 8 00:09:37 10000014
 9 00:00:00 10000014
10 00:00:15 10000014
# … with 20 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R split at those values where `as.POSIXct` yield `NA`, then `rbind` the result.

```
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
               by(x, cumsum(is.na(as.POSIXct(x, format="%T"))), function(x) 
                 cbind(as.character(x)[1], as.character(x)[-1])))
head(res)
#           V1       V2
# 1.1 10000007 01:33:28
# 1.2 10000007 00:00:05
# 2.1 10000010 00:00:39
# 2.2 10000010 00:02:21
# 2.3 10000010 00:05:59
# 2.4 10000010 00:40:40
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- structure(c(31L, 30L, 4L, 32L, 8L, 11L, 16L, 24L, 21L, 33L, 19L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 25L, 34L, 26L, 29L, 35L, 27L, 28L, 36L, 9L, 12L, 
15L, 7L, 2L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 18L, 22L, 23L, 20L, 17L, 14L), .Label = c("00:00:00", 
"00:00:01", "00:00:02", "00:00:05", "00:00:10", "00:00:15", "00:00:29", 
"00:00:39", "00:00:58", "00:01:08", "00:02:21", "00:03:42", "00:04:02", 
"00:04:29", "00:05:58", "00:05:59", "00:07:48", "00:07:52", "00:09:37", 
"00:09:39", "00:09:53", "00:10:18", "00:12:52", "00:40:40", "00:40:51", 
"00:41:44", "01:07:14", "01:25:27", "01:32:32", "01:33:28", "10000007", 
"10000010", "10000014", "10000022", "10000023", "1000003"), class = "factor")
```